# What is the correct process for transferring to a new transmitter?

Tags: opentx, taranis, software

I’m looking to upgrade from my QX7 to the new Radiomaster TX16S Hall when it comes out.

I have several models saved to my current radio, and I’d rather not go through the hassle of rebinding all of them.

I have seen the Oscar Liang tutorial about model transfers in OpenTX, however many people are reporting it doesn’t work.

My question is: what process can I use to transfer my models over to a new radio whilst also carrying over the receiver profiles so I don’t need to re-bind my models.

I’m not sure if it is possible so ‘you can’t’ would be a reasonable answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OpenTX companion application model save/restore feature *is* the proper way. I don't have an OpenTX radio, but that's what I've heard.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ifconfig I’ve not actually tried it - the TX16S is still on preorder, however some of the comments on the article say it pops up with bad errors so I’d like to make certain of what process to follow so I don’t do damage to my new radio.

Comment: For what it's worth, I doubt you can do damage to a radio with OpenTX companion. If it's worth anything, JB also says this is correct: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YUY2J8tJaM

Answer (score 3):

Transferring models shouldn't be a problem since both radios run OpenTX.

However,  you cannot transfer bindings unless you are also moving an external module to the new radio.  For example, if you move a crossfire module from the QX7 to the Radiomaster, all your models are still bound at the module level, no re-binding required.  But if you are going to be using the internal module of the new radio then re-binding is required.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that at least for FrSky D8, D16, ? you can put the RadioMaster TX16S into a "clone" mode where it binds to your older transmitter, and will clone the binding to its' internal MPM (ie you don't have to re-bind the Rx). Then you actually have TWO transmitters bound to the same receiver - especially useful if you want a backup radio you don't have to re-bind at an event.